# Ajax event is not triggering Validation (Facescontext)

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I have two field dates on my Jsf form.

Date 1 : DOB and Date 2: Date_Retire

When the user will select a date from Date_retire, it should be greater than 18 years old.

```
<h:outputText value="DOB:" />
<p:calendar pattern="mm/dd/yyyy" id="dob" value="#{ActorComponent.actor.dob}"
    required="false" converter="primefacesCalendarConverter" />

<h:outputText value="Date retired:" />
<p:calendar pattern="mm/dd/yyyy" id="dateretired" 
        value="#{ActorComponent.actor.dateretired}"
        required="false" converter="primefacesCalendarConverter" >
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{ActorComponent.minimumDate()}" 
        process= "dateretired"" >
</calendar>
```

Listener:

```
public void minimumDate(Calendar Object){
    Calendar dob=actor.getdob();
    dob.add(Calendar.Year,18);
    if(Object.before(dob)){              
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            "FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR", 
            new FacesMessage("Date is not valid."));
    }
}
```

The ajax is not working. Facescontext is not displaying the message. Anyone can help?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you have a component named `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR` in your view. Do you meant to generate a global message? Try passing `null` as the first parameter to `addMessage`. Also your view code needs a review. It's got at least two errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if "dateSelect" is a real event, try using "click" or "onclick"

```
<p:ajax event="click"
```